# What is this attribute?

Tags: c#, interop

I am pretty confused by the code I have found in some pathfinding example:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint="RtlZeroMemory")]
public unsafe static extern bool ZeroMemory(byte* destination, int length);
```

What does it mean? Why there are the brackets in the import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`DllImportAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) instructs the linker where to find the code for this function. That's how your program knows what to do when you call it.

In this specific case, the attribute indicates that the `ZeroMemory` method's implementation exists in `kernel32.dll`, where it is exported as `RtlZeroMemory`.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interoperability attribute. It allows a developer to call unmanaged code in other libraries through a .NET API.

The attibute in question is specifying that the actual implementation for the ZeroMemory method is in the external dll "Kernel32.dll"

Comment: It doesn't expose anything. It connects to functions already exposed in another assembly.

Comment: It tells the runtime where to find the definition of another function.

Answer (score 0):

The DllImportAttribute instructs the linker to dynamically link to a method in an external assembly.

The attribute has both required and optional parameters.
Optional parameters are called by name.

In this case the parameters are the name of the assembly and the name of the method within it that is invoked.